# xgboost custom early stopping function

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

It does not seem that xgboost support custom early stopping function. Right?

This page https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/callbacks.html says xgboost allows a custom metric and early_stopping_rounds to be specified.

What I need is custom early stopping function where you can specify the threshold for the metric, e.g., when the metric is above/below a threshold or stopped decreasing according to the threshold. Tensorflow Keras support such call back https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found this https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/examples/callbacks.html#sphx-glr-python-examples-callbacks-py.  Testing it now. Thanks.